# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `tintColor` supplied to `Text`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I am facing the following error when I use the code below:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `tintColor` supplied to `Text`

```
<Text
style={{
  tintColor: focused ? 'white' : 'black',
  fontSize: 14,
  fontFamily: 'SF Pro Text',
  marginBottom: 15
  }}
>
```

Comment: would you mind having a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Answer (score 1):

`tintColor` supposed to work only with `<Image>` components

Comment: How to apply tintColor on text?

Comment: @BhavinKathiriya You can set it's `color`, but `tintColor` is not going to work.